# OSX cpp (clang) error: no such file or directory: 'c'

Tags: macos, clang, c-preprocessor

I'm on OS X Mavericks 10.9.3. When I run a long `cpp` command, I get an opaque error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'c'
```

I've narrowed the error-generating command down to

```
cpp -I "."
```

- How can I fix this?
- Is there a way to force `cpp` to give me a more useful error message?
- *Bonus*: What could this possibly mean?

---

#### Appendix

To address a question in the comments

```
$ cpp --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Not to be unhelpful, but you are aware that `cpp` is not the frontend to clang, but rather part of the gcc code (which then uses the llvm backend)? You would normally use `clang` or `clang++` (or `gcc` or `g++` or `c++`)...

Comment: `cpp --version` on my system tells me clang/LLVM (cf. above). Or I can do `clang -E` to preprocess directly. But maybe you're right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By trial & error, I found I can fix the error by removing the space after `-I`

```
cpp -I"."
```

I'm assuming this is a behavior difference between `clang` `cpp` and other versions.

I still would like to know a better way to track down these kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the installation gives error about clang or clang++ ..then we need to find where clang and clang++ have been installed by using following command on Mac
xcodebuild -find clang

The output will be

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

after this we need to softlink the Xcode or command line binari

ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang /usr/bin/